# Finding the monotonicity of simple sequence - how to?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to find the monotonicity (whether it's increasing, decreasing or non-existeng) of such simple sequence: $$a_{n} = \sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n}$$

$$\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n}}{\sqrt[n+1]{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}}$$

I have dealt with such exercises before without problems. This one I have no idea how to proceed further.

Help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Easily seen from $a_n=3\sqrt[n]{(2/3)^n+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange things a bit

$$
a_n = 3\left[\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n + 1 \right]^{1/n}
$$

As $n$ increases the term $(2/3)^n$ goes to zero and $a_n$ monotonically decreases to $3$